# call document.ready function after page postback

Tags: jquery

I have the following function on my page. This function will select all the checkbox on Repeater control. It works great when page is 1st time loaded. But the function didn't call/work when I reload or refresh the page or select different criteria on the page (at postback). So as soon as I have postback on this, the document.ready() function doesn't call anymore. How can still call loadChkCtrls() function when page is at postback?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             checked = false;
             alert("test");
             loadChkCtrls();
             return;

         });

     function loadChkCtrls() {
         alert("test3");
         $("span.chkEachRow input").attr('checked', false);

         $("#chkAllRows").click(function() {
             alert("test1");
             if (checked == false) {
                 checked = true
             }
             else {
                 checked = false
             }
             $("span.chkEachRow input").attr('checked', checked);
             return;
         });
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. The following code worked for me.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType(), "scriptKey", "loadChkCtrls();", True)
```

Thanks,
Annie